# Django form wizard can't return to the first step after last summarized page

Tags: python, django, django-formwizard

I use SessionWizardView for gain initial data from user via wizard. I have four required steps and one optional (customed). After last step I forward to summarized page. If press refresh browser's button at this point I will expect redirect to the first page of my wizard. But in fact I redirected to second page, for some reason. Could anyone help me to undestand this behavior?

This is my templates:

```
TEMPLATES = {
    'select_type': "poneraapp/select_type.html",
    'select_features': "poneraapp/select_features.html",
    'select_model': "poneraapp/select_model.html",
    'set_objects_number': "poneraapp/set_objects_count.html",
    'select_support': "poneraapp/select_support.html"
}
```

My form list:

```
form_list = [
        ('select_type', FormStepOne),
        ('select_features', FormCustomStep),
        ('select_model', FormStepTwo),
        ('set_objects_number', FormStepThree),
        ('select_support', FormStepFour)
    ]
```

done function:

```
def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        self.storage.reset()
        
        return render(self.request, 'done.html', {
            'form_data': [form for form in form_list],
        })
```